# Limit concurrent queries in Spring JPA

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a simple rest endpoint that executes Postgres procedure.
This procedure returns the current state of device.
For example:
20 devices.
Client app connect to API and make 20 responses to that endpoint every second.
For x clients there are x*20 requests.
For 2 clients 40 requests.
It causes a big cpu load on Postgres server only if there are many clients and/or many devices.
I didn’t create it but I need to redesign it.
How to limit concurrent queries to db only for it? It would be a hot fix.

My second idea is to create background worker that executes queries only one in the same time. Then the endpoint fetches data from memory.

Comment: You can reduce the size of the connection pool - that essentially defines the number of concurrent queries your application can run

Comment: Why not just fix the clients so they stop doing that?  If you start throwing an error for 4 out of every 5 requests, how would the clients respond to that?  If you make each client wait for its answer, how would the clients respond to that?  You could add a field to the response to the clients saying "Hey knock it off", but unless the clients know what that means it wouldn't change anything.

Comment: Why not use native queries wherever possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would try the simple way first. Try to reduce

1. the amount of database connections in the pool OR
2. the amount of working threads in the build-in Tomcat.

More flexible option would be to put the logic behind a thread pool limiting the amount of working threads. It is not trivial, if the Spring context and database is used inside a worker. Take a look on a Spring annotation @Async.

*Offtopic: The solution we are discussing here looks like a workaround. The discussed solution alone will most probably increase the throughput only by factor 2 maybe 3. It is not JEE conform and it will be most probably not very stable. It is better to refactor the application avoiding such a problem. Another option would be to buy a new database server.*

**Update:** JEE compliant solution would be to implement some sort of bulkhead pattern. It will limit the amount of concurrent running requests and reject it, if the some critical number is reached. The server application answers with "503 Service Unavailable". The client application catches this status and retries a second later (see "exponential backoff").